# laravel [1049] Unknown database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am currently having issues when I try to view my database through a controller.  When I try to use a controller to view my data I get the following error.

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel'".

If I use artisan tinker I can do an ::all() and view my data, I have also successfully migrated my data over as well.  It just for some reason does not seem to like my views.

I have viewed other similar answers which suggested to run

`php artisan cache:clear`.

This however did not do anything for me.

controller:

```
class authorsController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $authorList = \App\Author::all();
        //return $authors;
        return view('library.authors');
    }
}
```

Inside .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=library
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Please run `php artisan tinker` and do `config('database')`. Check that it's picking up the right values - in particular, the `default` value, and the `mysql.database` one.

Comment: Check the values in `config/database.php`. If you have (and are using) multiple `connections`, one of them may not be configured to use `library` as your `database`. Check for `env('...', 'laravel');`; something may be using the default instead of `DB_DATABASE`

Comment: @ceejayoz I looked at `config('database')` and it shows that they are all the correct databases.

Comment: @PaulCarlson If you're certain of that, then check that `app/Author.php` doesn't have a `$connection` value set in it.

Comment: @TimLewis I looked at the `config/database.php` and it was looking good.  I even ran a search for "laravel" and it didnt turn up anything outside of comments.  I also looked at my .env file and that again is looking good with the proper database name.

Comment: Weird... And the default for `env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')` isn't `laravel`, so that thought was a stretch anyway. You say you can view the contents of `\App\Author::all()` using `php artisan tinker` without issue, so is there something being loaded in `library.authors` that could have it's own configuration separate from what you've defined? Or some middleware when accessing that route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running Laravel with `php artisan serve`, it's won't pick up `.env` changes until you stop and restart the server.

It's possible you had "laravel" set as your DB name when the server was started. Kill it and then run the command again.

Comment: This was it.  I did not think of re-starting the server after I made the changes.  Thank for the obvious answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this list of commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
```

After put this code in your route `web.php` and run in the browser this will give you a database is connected or not.

```
Route::get('/testConnection', function () {
try {
      DB::connection()->getPdo();
      if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
          echo "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
          die;
      }else{
          die("Could not find the database. Please check your configuration.");
      }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      die($e->GetMessage());
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that however it still says that I am using the wrong database.  It still gives me "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel".  Do you know the route that db information takes?  For example I know that I declare it in the `.env` which is then read in the `config.database.php`.  Is there a step in between or after that I am missing?

Comment: @Paul Carlson My suggestion is to create new database with name `laravel` and check error is gone or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to why still, but I did find a fix that worked for me.  Inside the `config.database.php` I changed `'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')` to `'database' => env('library', 'library')`.  I feel that I should not have to change those, but for what ever reason that corrected the issue.

It leads me to think that it had something to do with the `.env` file but not sure.  I will have to start a new project to verify that it is not something weird on my system.

Comment: That's super odd. But unless you have an entry in your `.env` file `library=library`, `env('library', 'library');` is simply defaulting to `library`, so you could effectively just put `'database' => library'`. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: The default values in config/database.php are actually pointing towards the values in .env.

Like this:

'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')

DB_DATABASE is a key that should NOT be changed. It refers to the key mentioned in .env. The method env() is used to retrieve the value from the .env file. Read about env() here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-env

Answer (score 0):

I tried php artisan config:clear. I tried php artisan cache:clear. I had the database created. I dropped it and re-created it a few times. I even tried using an existing database by changing the DB_DATABASE value in .env I could connect to the new and existing databases via CLI. I saw the drivers in php -m. So to fix this on Windows 10 was change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to DB_HOST=localhost in .env and cleared out config/cache again. Worked.